# Transparent image overlay over below view

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am pretty new to iOS and had a question regarding subview and their behaviour. I am trying to present a modal screen to the user upon login of a basic info screenshot. It has a bunch of tet bubbles that i want to display on top of the user login page so the user can get info on what the different options on the screen mean. Its like a transparent view on top of the screen behind it giving help texts overlays. What is the best way to do this? Currently i have a class for this overlay and i push a view in that class. but i cannot get the view below to show once i display the image overlay on top. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: It would help if you could post some code of how this is being implemented.  It is unclear if you would like to use a modal or simply display an image in your view.

Comment: i would like to simply display a transparent image over the current view so you can see both the view underneath and the help bubbles that the image has

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should set an image inside of an imageview and by setting UserInteractionEnabled to NO will allow you to click content beneath the image.

```
UIImageView *iview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thanks.png"]];
[iview setFrame:CGRectMake(5,5, iview.frame.size.width, iview.frame.size.height)];
[iview setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
[self.view addSubview:iview];
```

Comment: i dont want the content below to be clickable... i just want it to be visible but not be able to click around or drag around on it.

Comment: If you simply want an image with transparent portions then you need to create an image with transparency.  Saving your image out as a PNG with transparency should provide the desired effect.

Comment: the view underneath is scrollable... so if i put this image on top with transparency, i can still scroll below it and interact with the previous view. how can i stop this

Comment: `[yourImgView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];` would enable user interaction so your image is expecting touch events which would prohibit touch events from triggering on layers below.

Comment: with the above, i am still able to scroll

Comment: If you post your code as an edit to the original post I can add it to my sample project and hopefully be able to help solve the issue.  I'm wondering if the frame of the imageview is smaller than the scrollview, so the scrollview can be triggered outside of the frame of the image.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17950/discussion-between-john-baum-and-propstm)